# get best sales rep weekly SQL

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I need a bit of help with a SQL Server issue.

I have 2 tables:

```
complete_sales_raw                           
(
    Id int Identity(1,1) PK,                                 
    RepId int  FK in sale_reps,                                
    Revenue decimal(15,2),                    
    Sale_date datetime2(7)
)
```

and

```
sale_reps
(
    Id int Identity(1,1) PK, 
    RepName nvarchar(50)
)
```

What I need to do is get best sales rep based on the total revenue for each week, starting with 2014-06-01 and ending at current date.

Each week has 7 days and the first day is 2014-06-01.

So far I got to here:

```
SELECT TOP(1) 
    sr.RepName as RepName, 
    SUM(csr.Revenue) as Revenue 
INTO #tmp1
FROM complete_sales_raw csr
JOIN sale_reps sr on csr.RepId = sr.Id
WHERE DATEDIFF( d,'2014-06-01', Sale_date ) BETWEEN 0 and 6
GROUP BY sr.RepName
ORDER BY 2 desc
```

But this only returns the best sale rep for the first week and I need it for each week.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Use a Calendar table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an aggregation to get the total sales by week.  This requires some manipulation of the dates to calculate the number of weeks -- basically dividing the days by 7.

Then, use `rank()` (or `row_number()` if you only want one when there are ties) to get the top value:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT tsr.RepName as RepName,
             (DATEDIFF(day, '2014-06-01', MAS_PostDate ) - 1) / 7 as weeknum,
             SUM(csr.Revenue) as Revenue,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY (DATEDIFF(day, '2014-06-01', MAS_PostDate ) - 1) / 7 ORDER BY SUM(csr.Revenue)) as seqnum
      FROM complete_sales_raw csr JOIN
           sale_reps sr
           on csr.RepId = sr.Id
      WHERE DATEDIFF(day, '2014-06-01', MAS_PostDate ) BETWEEN 0 and 6
      GROUP BY sr.RepName, (DATEDIFF(day, '2014-06-01', MAS_PostDate ) - 1) / 7
     ) s
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: querry returns "Invalid column name 'weeknum'."

Comment: @PeterSandu . . . That's what I call "wishful coding".  The expression is needed rather than the column alias.

Answer (score 0):

ok so, I created a week table like so

```
IF ( OBJECT_ID('dbo.tmp4') IS NOT NULL ) 
   DROP TABLE dbo.tmp4
GO

Create Table tmp4(
StartDate datetime,Enddate datetime,WeekNo varchar(20)
) 

DECLARE
@start_date DATETIME,
@end_date DATETIME,
@start_date1 DATETIME,
@end_date1 DATETIME
DECLARE @Table table(StartDate datetime,Enddate datetime,WeekNo varchar(20))
Declare @WeekDt as varchar(10)
SET @start_date = '2014-06-01'
SET @end_date = '2015-01-03'

Set @WeekDt = DATEPART(WEEK,@start_date)
SET @start_date1 = @start_date

While @start_date<=@end_date
Begin
--Select @start_date,@start_date+1
IF @WeekDt<>DATEPART(WEEK,@start_date)
BEGIN
Set @WeekDt = DATEPART(WEEK,@start_date)
SET @end_date1=@start_date-1
INSERT INTO tmp4 Values(@start_date1,@end_date1,DATEPART(WEEK,@start_date1))
SET @start_date1 = @start_date
END

set @start_date = @start_date+1

END
GO
```

and then I used Gordon's answer and made this:

```
    SELECT t.StartDate as StartDate, sr.RepName as RepName, SUM(csr.Revenue) as             Revenue,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY (t.StartDate) ORDER BY SUM(csr.Revenue) desc) as seqnum into tmp1
FROM tmp4 t,
    complete_sales_raw csr
JOIN sale_reps sr on csr.RepId = sr.Id
WHERE DATEDIFF( d,t.StartDate, MAS_PostDate ) BETWEEN 0 and 6
GROUP BY sr.RepName, t.StartDate

SELECT * FROM tmp1
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY StartDate
```

which returns the best sales_rep for each week